# Can PHP be used to manipulate handlebarsjs expressions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I took the dive into javascript templating with Handlebars.js just about an hour ago. So far so good. I have items that upon click shoot out an ajax request to my controller which then grabs data via the related model and then passes it back to the jquery ajax call with `json_encode()`.

At that point I pass the returned data to a js function that renders the handlebars template along with the newly received data.

Everything is working just fine up to that point.

My problem and question are concerning the template creation itself. I'd like to do something simple like `<?=number_format({{Savings}});?>` but this seems to throw a big error such that the page doesn't even bother fully rendering.

Is there any way to integrate some PHP manipulation? Based on my small trial and error along with the server vs. client side deal going on I'm imagining it's not possible, but wanted to ask just in case. If not, what's the best method for doing this sort of data ironing (numbers, dates, letter cases, etc.) in this context?

Answer (score 1):

No it can't. Remember that PHP is generating the HTML, which is the handlebar template in this case. The template is send to the client (the browser), where the handlebar library processes it.

For PHP `{{ Savings }}` is just that, it's not a number on the server. It only becomes a number on the client. Therefor this will give you a PHP parse error.

You need to format a number with handlebar by using a helper. You might need to write a custom helper, which is described in the article ['Handlebars.js Part 2: Partials and Helpers'](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers).

Comment: @JohnBlythe If you have further questions please ask, if not please accept the answer (green checkmark).